# Sequence contains no elements error with inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a base class from which almost everything else inherits..

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int OwnerId{ get; set; }
   public virtual Org Owner{ get; set; }

}

public abstract class Party: MyBaseClass
{

}

public class Org: Party
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

My data context has a line like this:

```
public DbSet<Org> Orgs { get; set; }
```

When executing a query like this...

```
var orgs = db.Orgs;
```

I get this error:

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Org_Owner_Source' in relationship
>   'Org_Owner'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key
>   properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role
>   must be '*'.

In order to overcome this problem, I added the following Fluent API code:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyBaseClass>()
                .HasRequired(e => e.Owner)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.OwnerId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This resolves the `Invalid Multiplicity` error but when I subsequently run my query, it returns a "**Sequence contains no elements error**". When I inspect the generated SQL code that is hitting the database, I find that the query's '`from`' clause is referencing a non-existent MyBaseClassClasses table instead of the Orgs table as expected.

Running a migration also throws the '**Sequence contains no elements**' error. Anyway, I wouldn't want all the classes that inherit from `MyBaseClass` to be denormalized into a single MyBaseClassClasses table.

Questions:

1. Is the fluent api code correct in this situation?
2. If no, what should it be?
3. If yes, then how can I overcome the 'Sequence contains no elements' error?

******* Follow-up Edit **********************************

The other way I have been trying it is with the Fluid Mapping removed and the following class definitions:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("Owner")]
   public int OwnerId{ get; set; }
   public virtual Org Owner{ get; set; }

}

public abstract class Party: MyBaseClass
{

}

public class Org: Party
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

This solution throws the "Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Org_Owner_Source' in relationship 'Org_Owner'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'." error.

I was able to partially work around the problem as I discovered that any other class, besides Org, that inherits from MyBaseClass can have a lazy loading Owner attribute if the attribute is entered directly in to child class and a fluid api entry is made.

For example:

```
public class MyOtherClass: MyBaseClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Whaterver { get; set; }
   public virtual Org Owner{ get; set; }
}
```

With the fluid API entry:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyOtherClass>().HasRequired(x => x.Owner).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x=>x.OwnerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not the correct fluent mapping. By calling `modelBuilder.Entity<MyBaseClass>()`, you are telling Entity Framework that `MyBaseClass` is an entity and should somehow map to the database. Instead, use lowest class that you want mapped.

For example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Org>().HasRequired(e => e.Owner);
```

Comment: I tried with that mapping but it still throws the "Multiplicity is not valid" error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your mapping does result in a much better query, with the right table being queried, but the sequence is still empty for some reason.

Comment: Actually, this solution still didn't solve the problem. I still get either a Multiplicity is not valid error, Invalid Column "Owner_Id", or "Sequence is empty" error no matter what combinations of data annotations and fluid api entries I try.