# ASP.NET MVC Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to Asp.Net MVc. I have almost finished my project but a strange issue appeared in project.

As I try to run the project I get Error message.

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains no matching element
```

In one of my controller I am using the statement below to get all groups to display in a dropdownlist.

```
http://localhost....../Clients (trying to run this page) and getting error on the line containing code below.

 ViewBag.GroupDropDownValues   = new SelectList(db.Groups.OrderBy(m => m.groupId), "groupId", "groupName");
```

Or the other controller:

```
ViewBag.CategoryDropDownValues = new SelectList(db.Category.OrderBy(m => m.categoryId), "categoryId", "categoryName");
```

This happening in all the controllers that are using this syntax.

I need to display dropdownLists with values from database. Everything was working correctly till morning. I don't have idea where I changed and it started throwing these  errors.

I have already tried other solutions suggested in SO to use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`

like [Sequence contains no elements error with inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526294/sequence-contains-no-elements-error-with-inheritance?rq=1)

but nothing changed. I think I am not selecting a single value but a list of values.

Please suggest something or guide in right direction as will be thankful.

------------- Edit ---------------

```
@model App.Models.Policy

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "search-form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
<div class="span4 ">
   <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="groupId">Group</label>
       <div class="controls">

      @Html.DropDownList("Group", (SelectList)@ViewBag.GroupDropDownValues, 
      "---Select Group ---", new { @class = "m-wrap span12" })

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `.DefaultIfEmpty`, that will make `NULL` to default and then will do `group by`, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this like  ViewBag.GroupDropDownValues = new SelectList(db.np_groups.DefaultIfEmpty(), "group_id", "group_name");. but same issue.

Comment: If you closely look at `DefaultIfEmpty`, it takes parameter and that parameter is utilized as default value if there is `NULL`, e.g. http://www.dotnetperls.com/defaultifempty.

Comment: no it did'nt worked. :(

Comment: add your view cod for dropdownlist please?

Comment: @M.Azad I have edited question and added the code. Please have a look

Comment: Does @ViewBag.GroupDropDownValues has value?

Comment: @M.Azad it gives error on the line that contains ViewBag.CategoryDropDownValues = new SelectList(db.Category.OrderBy(m => m.categoryId), "categoryId", "categoryName"); in controller. and stucks there. not go to the view

Comment: it does not go to view @ViewBag but gives error  in controller at the line above.

Comment: @ThinkingWeb maybe categoryId or categoryName not defined in Category

Comment: @M.azad both fields are defined in model.